# How to highlight nickname instead of first name/last name?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, contacts

I would like to highlight nicknames in the contact list using a bigger font and first/last name under that, in smaller font (practically opposite as implemented by default)

Is it possible?

I am running Android 2.2 (CM6.0.1)

Comment: Not with the stock Contacts app.

Comment: Could you suggest me a different way to reach the result? Another rom, or a market app?

Comment: There are quite a few Contact List replacement apps in the market, you won't need to root or replace your ROM since the default Contact apps is just another regular Android application. I haven't actually used them, so I can't recommend any good ones, so you will have to play with them and see which ones you'll like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried [Go Contacts](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jbapps.contact&hl=en) and Go Dialer and it seems really handy with useful features and beautiful look!

P.S I wanted to post a comment but I don't have adequate permission for "comment everywhere" right now!

Comment: This seems like an answer to me.

Comment: The app is no longer available. How do solve this issue these days?